# Moving canvas with translate() method

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

According to MDN documentation `translate()` method "moves the canvas and its origin" but the below code does not move the border of the canvas. If the `translate()` method moves the canvas shouldn't the border move as well?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Temp</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        canvas.width = 300;
        canvas.height = 300;

        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.
If you want to offset your canva, why not just do this?

```
document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.transform = "translate(50%, 50%)";
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the MDN documentation for `translate()` method. It says the method moves the "canvas" and the origin. So why doesn't the border move with the canvas?

Comment: The borders follow your canva, if you inspect the element you will see that your canva has simply not moved.

Try replacing lines 23 and 24 with my code